# lastInsertId() creates 2 duplicate records in database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

So I've got a PHP page that inserts a booking into my database, and I am using the method `lastInsertId()` to present the user with their Booking ID (which is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` in the database).

The problem is, two duplicate records are being added when the code runs, and the method is returning the second Booking ID. Can someone shed some light on why this is happening?

This is the code:

```
<?php

...

$stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT bookings (DateFrom, DateTo, GuestHouseID_FK, GuestID_FK, RoomID_FK) VALUES (:DateFrom, :DateTo, :GuestHouseID_FK, :GuestID_FK, :RoomID_FK)'); 
$stmt->bindParam(':DateFrom', $DateFrom, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':DateTo', $DateTo, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
$stmt->bindParam(':GuestHouseID_FK', $GuestHouseID_FK, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt->bindParam(':GuestID_FK', $GuestID_FK, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':RoomID_FK', $RoomID_FK, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute(); 
echo '<H3>'; 
echo 'Thank you. Your booking has been completed!'; 
echo '</H3>'; 
if($stmt->execute()){
    $booking_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    echo "Your Booking ID is " . $booking_id;
    echo '<hr>';
}
echo '<p>Click here to return to the main menu</p>';
echo '<form action="@AT2_main_menu.html">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Main menu">';
echo '</form>';
}
catch(PDOException $e) 
{
  echo "Something's gone wrong. Please try again or contact the admin"; 
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

Comment: You execute your statement two times try to comment one `$stmt->execute(); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running `$stmt->execute()` twice. When you call it inside the `if` statement you're calling it a second time. Remove your first call to the function.